# More informal verb to go with "rapport"

Tags: single-word-requests, tone

I want to say that two people established a good rapport.  But the context is quite informal, and "established" sounds stuffy in my context.  What other verb(s) could I use in place of *establish* here?

**Edit**: I've been asked for more information about the context.  Background: my son, M., was resisting going to the suggested appointments with the school social worker, Ms. D.  Email to school point person:

> M. went to the first appointment with Ms. D. today.  They (started to establish) rapport, and [*etc*].

I would like to know more verbs that can be used with *rapport* instead of *establish*.  The ones I already knew were *build, create, feel, get going (i.e. get a good rapport going)*.  Also, I'm not sure when to use an article and when to use a qualifier (e.g. built rapport, built a rapport, built good rapport, built a good rapport).  I'm wondering if the concept of *good* is built in already.

Comment: Build, Create, form, forged, etc.

Comment: *have*...........

Comment: Please do see the tag info for [single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). There's a checklist at the end.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Could you be more specific about what's missing?  Context?  I want to describe the results of my son's first appointment with the school social worker (which he had resisted going to, but which went surprisingly well).  Criteria -- I've seen hundreds of questions that don't give a rubric.  I did say, though, that an informal tone was important.  Words I didn't like: *establish, build*.  Perhaps the problem is that I didn't show thesaurus words I considered?

Comment: Yes: you need to say what you've considered and rejected. The fact that it's a boy and a mentor of some description might be useful, too. There may be words more appropriate for that situation than a good relationship between an aged aunt and her equally-aged gardener, for example. (For instance, *hit it off* might work in your case, where it wouldn't really work for the older generation.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Better?

Comment: Rapport is even more stuffy than established. To be informal you need to replace both. 'They became friendly', 'they started to get along'.

Answer (score 1):

Rapport is far more stuffy than established I would say. If you are looking for an alternative sentence you might try: -

> Two people got to know each other

or

> They got to know each other quite well

See [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90694/to-get-to-know-someone-vs-to-know-someone) for a short discussion about the meaning of the term.

If you want to keep *rapport* but just don't like the word established, developed works fine:

> Two people *developed* a good rapport

Comment: "They got along well"--that's more informal.

Comment: Maybe you're right.  I'm going to say *they hit it off with a good rapport*.

Answer (score 0):

"Bond" or "Bonded" would the word I would use... but that could have connotations that you may not want to imply.

eg: the 2 new students bonded during their first school camping trip..

but as a direct replacement of the word "established" as used in your example, I would perhaps suggest "built up", or (as Gary noted "developed")